# How to send additional data elements in Jenkins Notification Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, notifications, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I use Jenkins Pipeline Jobs and invoke build using its remote API's.

I also use [Build Notification plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Notification+Plugin)  to invoke my API once the build is complete for further downstream automation. As per the plugin documentation, it provides a fixed set of data elements from the build. However as part of the build, the Job has generated some data elements which I need to provide it back to my API which gets invoked by Notification plugin (As part of the JSON Payload). Can someone help me how do pass additional data elements through this plugin? or any better ways of doing it?

For example, 
1. When the pipeline job is configured with notification endpoint, the jenkins config XML has the following entry

```
<com.tikal.hudson.plugins.notification.HudsonNotificationProperty plugin="notification@1.11">
  <endpoints>
    <com.tikal.hudson.plugins.notification.Endpoint>
      <protocol>HTTP</protocol>
      <format>JSON</format>
      <url>http://localhost/api/postStatus</url>
      <event>finalized</event>
      <timeout>30000</timeout>
      <loglines>20</loglines>
    </com.tikal.hudson.plugins.notification.Endpoint>
  </endpoints>
</com.tikal.hudson.plugins.notification.HudsonNotificationProperty>
```

2. A pipeline script just builds an image and the image ID has to be sent in the notification

Comment: Please post a simplified code of what you have right now, it'll be easier to make concrete suggestions

Comment: @PatriceM. Have edited the question. The notification API is just in Jenkins configuration. There is no pipeline step for it

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a perfect solution in the existing Jenkins Notification Plugin. However the solution that I used it to pass the data as part of the Log Text and parse the information in the other side.